# Is it possible to show a satellite map on Windows 10 UA app

Tags: windows-10, bing-maps, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make my first Windows 10 UA desktop app. I have a working map, but it shows the road type of map. The problem with this is, the detail isn't there, and may people won't be able to get enough info out of this.
Is there a way I can switch the map view from a road to a satellite map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for response

Sorry I miss understood, didn't realize you where using the MapControl class. Below is a link that explains how to use 3d aerial and street views (towards the bottom) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219695.aspx

the code you are looking for is something like

```
 MapControl1.Style = MapStyle.Aerial3DWithRoads;
```

Absolutely! You can use the Bing maps API. http://www.microsoft.com/maps/choose-your-bing-maps-API.aspx

Here is a link to a guide on getting started.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428643.aspx

From the API you can then select the satellite map instead of the road.

Comment: Unless if I'm missing something, I can't find where you can change the map view from road to satellite map
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn615001.aspx

As I said in my first post. This is the first Windows 10 app I made. So, I'm not sure what to look for.
I'm use to working on Android systems.

Comment: Responded above. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Thanks, it worked. 
For anyone wanting to get a high zoom. You may want to add this in a button because you can't zoom in as much